# C - Program automatically setting sticky bit?

Tags: c, io, permissions

I have this code where I am reading from a file and writing to another one the stuff that I read. For some reason I am constantly getting permission errors, but only when I create a new file and try to write; if I remove the block that reads and writes, it creates the file just fine and with the correct permissions. Once I try to write, however, the permissions on the created file look like this: `rwSr-Sr--`

```
 if ((dst_fd = open(dst_path, O_RDWR | O_CREAT)) < 0){
       close(src_fd);
       exit(1);
 }
 while ((n = read(src_fd, buf, BUF_SIZE)) > 0){
      if (write(dst_fd, buf, n) < 0){
          exit(1);
      }
 }
```

Why is this happening? I can't seem to find what I changed that made this start happening but I don't think I'm really doing anything that bad.

Comment: From the man page for open: *"The `oflag` argument may indicate that the file is to be created if it does not exist (by specifying the `O_CREAT` flag).  In this case, open() requires an additional argument `mode_t mode`."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the documentation for open. The signature is:

```
int _open(
   const char *filename,
   int oflag [,
   int pmode] 
);
```

Notice pmode. It's optional, and you're not using it.

You're using oflag, which is informing open the operations you intend to perform, but sets no permissions. Instead, the default permissions established by umask will be applied by default. If you want to control permissions, you need to include pmode as well.

The documentation for open says that pmode is required when `O_CREAT` is used, which you have.

So, add the permissions you want, usually `_S_IREAD | S_IWRITE`.

Like:

```
open(dst_path, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, _S_IREAD | S_IWRITE))
```

You may need to check headers associated with these flags:

```
<fcntl.h>, <sys\types.h>, <sys\stat.h>
```

Comment: Pmode is not optional with O_CREAT. Calling open with O_CREAT and no mode argument is undefined behaviour; it does *not* use some default.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't notice that it was required for O_CREAT.

Comment: rici, you may notice that in my answer I said that, as in: "the documentation for open says that pmode is required when O_CREAT is used". The pmode parameter is option IN THE SIGNATURE. Maybe I didn't make that absolutely clear, but it's accurate. It is an optional parameter that is further required when using O_CREAT.